# How do i store sequence of 2D matrices into a 3D array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix, 3d

I have these series of 2D CT images and i have been able to read them into Matlab using "imread". The issue however is that i need the image read-in as a single 3D matrix rather than stack of several 2D matrices. I have been made aware that it is possible to store the number of 2D layers as the 3rd dimension, but i have no idea how to do this as i am still a learner.
The code i have for reading in the 2D stack are as follows:

```
a = dir('*.tif');                   

for i = 1: numel(a)
     b           = imread(a(i).name);    %read in the image              
     b_threshold = graythresh(b);        %apply threshold            
     b_binary    = im2bw(b, b_threshold);   %binarize image

     [m, n]      = size(b);              %compute the size of the matrix
     phi(i)      = ((m*n) - sum((b_binary(:))))/(m*n);   %compute the fraction of pore pixels in the image
     phi(:,i)    = phi(i);               %store each of the above result
end
```

I have added just a single image although several of these are needed. Nevertheless, one can easily duplicate the image to create a stack of 2D images. For the code to work, it is however important to rename them in a numerical order.[pore_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxah4.png)
Any help/suggestions/ideas is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: I want to remember (because you are new) that you can accept one of the answer. So please do it, if you appreciate one them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first advice is try to don't use the variable `i` and `j` in matlab because they are reserved (have a look [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/j.html)).
After it depends on along which dimension you want to store the 2D images:

1. if you want to store the images along the first dimension just use this code:

   ```
   a = dir('*.tif');                   

   for ii = 1: numel(a)
       b           = imread(a(ii).name);    %read in the image              
       b_threshold = graythresh(b);        %apply threshold            
       b_binary    = im2bw(b, b_threshold);   %binarize image

       [m, n]      = size(b);              %compute the size of the matrix
       phi(ii)      = ((m*n) - sum((b_binary(:))))/(m*n);   %compute the fraction of pore pixels in the image
       phi(:,ii)    = phi(ii);               %store each of the above result
       matrix_3D_images(ii,:,:)=b_binary;   %adding a new layer
   end
   ```

If you want to store the images along other dimensions it is easy to do: just change the posizion of the "pointer" `ii`:

2. `matrix_3D_images(:,ii,:)=b_binary;` or
3. `matrix_3D_images(:,:,ii)=b_binary;`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign along the third dimension using `i` as your index

```
stack_of_images(:,:,i) = b_binary
```